# cloud drive usage in Android App

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, google-drive-api

I am planing to make an android app which download required files from cloud drive Amazon or Google drive.

**Details:**
Let we have 30 lectures on cloud drive user can download a lecture {according to need/Intrest} from cloud drive using my android app.
Just i need is the public URL of the data stored in cloud drive. Or any API that can do this job {Amazon, google drive...etc}

How to do this ? **is there any Cloud API or something that help me ?**

Comment: That's a wonderful plan. What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How to do this ? is there any API or something that help me ?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of APIs available. [Amazon's API/SDK is here](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/). Rackspace has one as well, iirc. Google Drive and Dropbox aren't really public-facing cloud-storage, and you would probably want to look very closely at their TOS before utilizing them. For any public-facing services, I generally use a small php-app which talks to the mobile app and delivers the time-limited url for the requested content. This prevents side-loading and allows me to switch CDN providers without changing the app.

To get a more specific answer, you probably need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thnaks, is there any sample code that can help me; initially i just need to use clud drive just to download data

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to host a number of video lectures and have any user download them you probably want to use Amazon S3.  Cloud drive is for each user of the application to download and upload videos to their (the end user's) cloud drive account.  Google drive is similar.  Amazon S3 lets you (the developer) hold onto the data and then give it to your users.

- The Android SDK for AWS can be found https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/
- A getting started guide is http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/Welcome.html
- Specifically content on uploading and downloading with S3 is http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-store-retrieve-s3-transferutility.html (short version) and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html (more detail)

You can also find a sample on GitHub (along with a tutorial) https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably sounds like huge overkill, but if anything changes in the future (and it will), this will help you enormously.

I'd probably create a web service that responded with HTTP redirects to a URL where the content currently is.  If hosting cost is the issue, you could probably remain within the free tier on GAE pretty easily.

Amazon S3 is probably a decent fit here. Costs will probably be very low unless you start using a ton of bandwidth.

Comment: is there any tutorial sample for this; i can code android but not know how to use this cloud drive

Answer (score 0):

Now amazon have the cloud drive service with unlimited space for ~60$ per year.
Also have api for [android](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/sdk-android-building-file-explorer).

Comment: The question was for if any api is present

Comment: I told him that amazon cloud drive has now an api for android. He ask for an api for amazon drive or google drive. The previous answers was regarding S3 services which are more expensive. Can you tell me what I missed ?